# Wrapping derived class method from base class

Tags: python, oop, metaclass, python-class, python-datamodel

Imagine I have a base and a derived class like so:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

I wish to wrap calls `foo` calls made by instances of `B`. Modifying any part of B is not allowed (I don’t own B).

What I have as of now:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        fnames = ["foo"]
        for fname in fnames:

            def capture(f):
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    print("wrapped")
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)

                return wrapper

            meth = capture(getattr(self, fname))
            bound = meth.__get__(self)
            setattr(self, fname, bound)


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("b")


o = B()
o.foo()

print(o.foo)
```

This works as expected, however I am concerned about this being inefficient memory-wise.

`o.foo` is a `<bound method A.__init__.<locals>.capture.<locals>.wrapper of <__main__.B object at 0x10523ffd0>>`. It would seem that I would have to pay the cost of 2 closures for each instance I create.

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a metaclass based approach?

Comment: When I try this, it works, but `pylint` complains about the line with the call to `__get__` with `E1120: No value for argument 'type' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)`. I have this code in 2 places and it additionally complains `E1111: Assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return (assignment-from-no-return)` for one of the 2 places?! However, the doc shows `__get__`'s prototype as being `(__instance: object, __owner: type | None = None, /) -> Any`. How should I sate the linter for this code?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are planning to have several thousands instances of these live at the same time, the resource usage of doing so should not concern you - it is rather small compared with other resources a running Python app will use.

Just for comparison: asyncio coroutines and tasks are the kind of object which one can create thousands of in a process, and it is just "ok", will have a similar overhead.

But since you have control of the *base* class for `B` there are several ways to do it, without resorting to "monkey patching" - which would be modifying B in place after it was created. That is often the only alternative when one has to modify a class for which they don't control the code.

Wrapping the method either automatically, when it is retrieved from a `B` instance, in a lazy way, can spare even this - and sure can be more elegant than wrapping at the base class `__init__`:

If you know beforehand the methods you have to wrap, and is sure they are implemented in subclasses of classes which you control, this can be made by crafting a specialized `__getattribute__` method: this way, the method is wrapped only when it is about to get used.

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def _capture(f):  # <- there is no need for this to be inside __getattribute__
                  # unless the wrapper is to call `super()`
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapped")
        return f(*args, **kwargs) 
        # ^ "f" is already bound when we retrieve it via super().__getattribute__
        # so, take care not to pass "self" twice. (the snippet in the question
        # body seems to do that)
    return wrapper

class A:
    
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        fnames = {"foo", }
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if name in fnames:
            # ^ maybe add aditional checks, like if attr is a method,
            # and if its origin is indeed in a
            # class we want to change the behavior
            attr = partial(_capture(attr), self)  
            # ^ partial with self as the first parameter
            # has the same effect as calling __get__ passing
            # the instance to bind the method
            
        return attr
            
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

---

As for wrapping `foo` when B is created, that could give use even less resources - and while it could be done in a metaclass, from Python 3.6 on, the `__init_subclass__`  special method can handle it, with no need for a custom metaclass.

However, this approach can be tricky if the code might further subclass B in a `class C(B):`  which will again override  `foo`: the wrapper could be called multiple times if the methods use `super()` calls to `foo` in the base classes. Avoiding the code in the wrapper to run more than once would require some complicated state handling (but it can be done with no surprises).

```
from functools import wraps

def _capture(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapped")
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs) 
        # ^ "f" is retrieved from the class in __init_subclass__, before being 
        # bound, so "self" is forwarded explicitly
    return wrapper

class A:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        fnames = {"foo",}
        for name in fnames:
            if name not in cls.__dict__:
                continue
            setattr(cls, name, _capture(getattr(cls, name)))
            # ^no need to juggle with binding the captured method:
            # it will work just as any other method in the class, and
            # `self` will be filled in by the Python runtime itself.
            
            # \/ also, no need to return anything.
        
            
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

Comment: The __getattribute__ answer is really good, I have one suggestion to improve it. Using types.MethodType(attr, self) is better than using partial(_capture(attr), self) since partial doesn't have a descriptor so the returned attribute is not bound to the class instance.

just need to fix the return wrapper to
'
def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapped")
        return f(*args, **kwargs) 
        # ^ "f" is retrieved from the class in __init_subclass__, before being 
        # bound, so "self" is forwarded explicitly
    return wrapper
'

Answer (score 0):

Following @jsbueno answer

Using

`types.MethodType(attr, self)`

is better than using

```
partial(_capture(attr), self)
```

since partial doesn't have a descriptor so the returned attribute is not bound to the class instance. just need to fix the return wrapper to

```
def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("wrapped")
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
```